# Replacing several characters with newline

Tags: sed, scripting, newlines

I have a file with data that looks like this:

```
0.5, 14, 14, 12, 1.000000736101224E-11, -- 0.5, 14, 14, 14, 9.999999999999996E-12,
```

How can I replace `, --` with a newline?

I tried `sed 's/,\ --/\n/'` but it did not work.

Comment: Why is there a \?  `sed -i 's/, -- /\n/g' file` seems to work

Comment: @guillermochamorro That depends on whether you're using GNU `sed` or not. The backspace does nothing in that position, so if it doesn't work with it then it wouldn't work without it either (if they aren't using GNU `sed`, e.g. on a macOS system, or some other non-Linux system).

Answer (score 1):

It can be tricky to force a newline into sed's `s///` command.

Assuming you also want to tidy the spaces before and after `--`, awk is a good candidate:

```
$ awk -F' *-- *' -v OFS='\n' '{$1=$1}1' file
0.5, 14, 14, 12, 1.000000736101224E-11,
0.5, 14, 14, 14, 9.999999999999996E-12,
```

`$1=$1` is an awk idiom that forces the current record to be rewritten using a different field separator.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help! I greatly appreciate it. This has been giving me trouble all morning.

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU `sed`:

```
$ gsed 's/, -- /\n/' file
0.5, 14, 14, 12, 1.000000736101224E-11
0.5, 14, 14, 14, 9.999999999999996E-12,
```

Standard `sed` does however not allow inserting newlines with the `s` command, but you could possibly make use of the fact that appending from the hold space would *add* a newline to the pattern space:

```
$ sed 'h;s/, -- .*//;G;s/\(\n\).*, -- /\1/' file
0.5, 14, 14, 12, 1.000000736101224E-11
0.5, 14, 14, 14, 9.999999999999996E-12,
```

This copies the pattern space (the line) to the hold space with `h`, then it deletes the last bit so that only the "first line" remains.  It then appends the copy of the original data to the pattern space with an embedded newline as delimiter with `G`.  The bit between the newline and the pattern that we treat as our delimiter is replaced by the newline and the result is printed.

There is quite possibly a more elegant way of doing this with non-GNU `sed`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I did not know that the sed does not insert newlines. Thanks for introducing me to gsed.

Answer (score 0):

@glenn jackman and @Kusalananda are correct, there is a trick to using a newline in the `sed` replacement string.  And yes, this is non-GNU sed (BSD).

The trick is to quote the argument portion of the -e flag, since the argument contains a newline.  The first part of the trick is that using quotes allows one to put a literal newline into the -e replacement token; and the second part is that such a newline needs to be backslash-escaped for `sed`.  In script syntax, it looks like:

```
sed -Ee "s/, +-- +/\\
/" < test.txt
```

Typed manually at the command line (and with `bash`'s continuation prompt `>`), it looks more like:

```
$ sed -Ee "s/, +-- +/\\
> /" < test.txt
0.5, 14, 14, 12, 1.000000736101224E-11
0.5, 14, 14, 14, 9.999999999999996E-12,
```

Inside the quotes, the double-backslash converts to a single backslash, because sed requires (literal?) newlines in the replacement string to be backslash-escaped.  Without the double-backslash, you'll see it complain:

```
$ sed -Ee "s/, +-- +/  
/" < test.txt
sed: 1: "s/, +-- +/
/
": unescaped newline inside substitute pattern
```

Answer (score -1):

With sed command it worked fine for me

command

```
echo "0.5, 14, 14, 12, 1.000000736101224E-11, -- 0.5, 14, 14, 14, 9.999999999999996E-12,"| sed "s/, -- /\n/g"
```

output

```
0.5, 14, 14, 12, 1.000000736101224E-11
0.5, 14, 14, 14, 9.999999999999996E-12,
```

Comment: Praveen, the OP said explicitly: "I tried `sed 's/,\ --/\n/'` but it did not work."

Comment: i have not used \ before --

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/526914/replacing-several-characters-with-newline/527045?noredirect=1#comment975107_526914